# javascript check if dictionary

Tags: javascript

I have a simple program like:

```
var a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
console.log(a)
console.log(a instanceof Array)
console.log(a.constructor instanceof Array)
```

Here the value of `a` is a dictionary. I want to check for it.

How can I check it in javascript? Both tests above give me false result.

Comment: Javascript does not have dictionary. It has object. Object and Array both have type object, so if you wish to distinguish between them, you can try `Array.isArray`. This will return true for array and false for objects

Answer (score 61):

The simplest approach to check if something is a dictionary in Javascript in a way that will **not** also return `true` when given an array is:

```
if (a.constructor == Object) {
    // code here...
}
```

This was inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218798/in-javascript-how-can-we-identify-whether-an-object-is-a-hash-or-an-array).

Comment: I like this approach. Tested against `string`, `number`, `Date`, `RegExp` and `Array`, they all returned `false`. Only a dictionary seems to return `true`

Comment: I would use `a.constructor.name == 'Object'`

Comment: Alan, what's the advantage of `a.constructor.name == 'Object'` vs. `a.constructor == Object`?

Answer (score 9):

```
function isDict(v) {
    return typeof v==='object' && v!==null && !(v instanceof Array) && !(v instanceof Date);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly in all cases. If the input is a `RegExp`, then the output is `true` instead of `false`.

Comment: The answer here solves this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304401/javascript-check-if-dictionary/51285298#51285298 .

Comment: `isDict(new class A {})` is true. You are checking for Date objects, but there are more classes on this planet than Date

Answer (score 7):

The structure `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` is a Javascript object.  It can be used sort of like a dictionary, but a [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is closer to what most people think of as a dictionary.

```
console.log(typeof a);            // "object"
console.log(Array.isArray(a));    // false, because it's not an array
```

If you want to know if something is an array, then use:

```
Array.isArray(a)
```

If you want to know if something is an object, then use:

```
typeof a === "object"
```

But, you will have to be careful because an Array is an object too.

---

If you want to know if something is a plain object, you can look at what jQuery does to detect a plain object:

```
isPlainObject: function( obj ) {
    // Not plain objects:
    // - Any object or value whose internal [[Class]] property is not "[object Object]"
    // - DOM nodes
    // - window
    if ( jQuery.type( obj ) !== "object" || obj.nodeType || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Support: Firefox <20
    // The try/catch suppresses exceptions thrown when attempting to access
    // the "constructor" property of certain host objects, ie. |window.location|
    // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=814622
    try {
        if ( obj.constructor &&
                !hasOwn.call( obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf" ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        return false;
    }

    // If the function hasn't returned already, we're confident that
    // |obj| is a plain object, created by {} or constructed with new Object
    return true;
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a question about JavaScript but here's the TypeScript version of the @Floyd answer

#### Typescript version

```
function isRecord(object: unknown): object is Record<keyof never, unknown> {
  return object instanceof Object && object.constructor === Object
}
```

#### @Floyd's answer

```js
if (a.constructor == Object) {
    // code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An inefficient but more rigorous way is to use JSON (This will exclude other classes and "associative arrays" from being counted as  'object'). Note that it is **not** a performance & memory -efficient solution. This is can only be recommended for test purposed:

```
function isDict(v) {
    return !!v && typeof v==='object' && v!==null && !(v instanceof Array) && !(v instanceof Date) && isJsonable(v);
}

function isJsonable(v) {
    try{
        return JSON.stringify(v) === JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v)));
     } catch(e){
        /*console.error("not a dict",e);*/
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to check either your dict(data) is a dictionary or not !

```
var dict = { a: 1, b: { c: 3, d: 4 }, e: 9 };

// this function will true / false

const isDict = dict => {
  return typeof dict === "object" && !Array.isArray(dict);
};

console.log(isDict(dict));  // true
```

this will return you true if it is a dictionary otherwise return false

Comment: `isDict(new Date())` is true

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is created using curly braces e.g. `{'foo': 'bar'}` (literal notation) or with the constructor `new Object()`. The term "dictionary" is used when discussing Python code and "object" when discussing JS code. Building on that, in Python we would use `isinstance({'foo': 'bar'}, dict)` to determine if some data point is a dictionary data type.

The equivalent check in JavaScript will utilize the fact that any "object" which is initialized from the [`Object()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object) constructor or [literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) will be an [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) the `Object` class and make use of the Object() constructor. Therefore, we can always verify that `foo.constructor == Object` is `true` for `{}` or `new Object()`. That tells us the data type is specifically `object` and not an array.

```js
const obj = { foo: "bar" };
console.log(obj instanceof Object); // true
console.log(obj.constructor == Object); // true

const objTwo = new Object();
console.log(objTwo.constructor == Object); // true

const arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr instanceof Array); // true
console.log(arr.constructor == Array); // true
console.log(arr instanceof Object); // true
console.log(arr.constructor == Object); // false
```

JavaScript defines arrays as predefined objects, where the indexes are the arrays properties. So although `[1,2] instanceof Object` is `true`, it will still be `false` for `[1,2].constructor == Object`. This is because the "array" is an object of the `Array` class which utilizes the `Array()` constructor and not the `Object()` constructor. This can cause some confusion, but remember when trying to determine if something is an "object" (dictionary for those with a Python background), checking the underlying constructor being used for object creation will quickly determine if your dealing with an "object" `{}` or an "array" `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the **toString** method in Object.prototype, This works like a charm in all the cases(Array,null,undefined etc).

```
var array_var=[1,2];
var dict_var={
'a':'hey',
'b':'hello'
};
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(dict_var) === '[object Object]');//returns true
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(array_var) === '[object Object]');//returns false
```

In short the toString method is used to represent the object, for example the toString method for an array returns '[object Array]'

Answer (score -2):

Would that work ?

```
function isDictObj(obj: any) {
  try {
    const test = {...obj}
  } catch(err) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

My logic is that if it is a dictionnary object (key:values), then using spread operator with {} should work, otherwise throw an exception

Comment: `isDictObj(new Date())` is true