# Use fetch to send get request with data object

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I'm using Fetch ([Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)) in a project and I would like to, for consistence purposes, create a function that receives all the parameters such as method, url and data and creates the correct request, depending if it's a GET or a POST request.

Is it possible, using Fetch, to send a data object that for the GET request, converts data into and string with the parameters and if it is a POST request, it just sends the data object in the body?

It would look like this:

```
fetch ('/test', {
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
           test: 'test'
        }
});
```

This doubt was inspired by this jQuery ajax behaviour:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/test',
   method: 'GET',
   data: {
      test: 'test'
   }
});
```

This would produce this request:

```
'/test/?test=test'
```

Comment: Well, yes, this is possible. But what is your question exactly? (note: you are aware of the fact that IE and safari don't support this?)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, it's just for an experiment :)
My question is:
If I pass the data object as normal in the fetch constructor for a GET request, would it send the request like the example I gave '/test/?test=test' ?

Comment: [Did you try it](https://i.imgur.com/buUeJ0c.jpg) ?

Comment: I tried it but I was more interested in the iteration through the multiple properties in the data object. Besides I searched for this question here and I couldn't find nothing, so I decided to create a topic that might be useful to other developers. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If I pass the data object as normal in the fetch constructor for a
>   GET request, would it send the request like the example I gave
>   '/test/?test=test'

If you want to add query string to a fetch request :

[From the SPEC](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api)

```
var url = new URL("https://a.com/method"),
params = {a:1, b:2}
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
fetch(url)
```

this will produce a request :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you could either use the [Url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) class:

```
var url = new URL("/test/")
Object.keys({test: 'test', a: 1}).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
fetch(url);
```

or parse the string yourself, if you want wider browser support:

```js
var params = {test: 'test', a: 1},
    qs = Object.keys(params).reduce(function(_qs, k, i){ return _qs + '&' + k + '=' + params[k]; }, '').substring(1);

console.log(qs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you snippets for creating query with and without using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

The code will be in [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) for the if you're using it. if not, just remove types, it will work in the same way.

#### Simple solution (URLSearchParams)

```
/**
 * Creates query from given object
 * - It doesn't work with deep nesting
 * - It doesn't remove empty fields
 * @returns `state1=6&state2=horse` without `?`
 */
function createQuery(queryObject?: Record<string | number, unknown> | null): string {
  if (queryObject == null) return ""
  // Typescript: The `as ...` expression here is ok because `URLSearchParams` will convert non-string by itself
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryObject as Record<string, string>)
  return searchParams.toString()
}
```

#### Solving problems solution (URLSearchParams)

```
/**
 * Creates query from given object
 * - It doesn't work with deep nesting
 * - Removes empty fields
 * @returns `state1=6&state2=horse` without `?`
 */
function createQuery(queryObject?: Record<string | number, unknown> | null): string {
  if (queryObject == null || !Object.keys(queryObject).length) return ""
  for (const key in queryObject) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(queryObject, key)) {
      const value = queryObject[key]
      // Use `!value` expression if you want to delete values as `0` (zero) and `""` (empty string) too.
      if (value == null) delete queryObject[key]
    }
  }
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryObject as Record<string, string>)
  return searchParams.toString()
}
```

#### No URLSearchParams solution

```
/**
 * Creates query from given object
 * - Supports prefixes
 * - Supports deep nesting
 * - Removes empty fields
 * @returns `state1=6&state2=horse` without `?`
 */
function createQuery(queryObject?: Record<string | number, unknown> | null, keyPrefix?: string): string {
  if (queryObject == null || !Object.keys(queryObject).length) return ""
  keyPrefix = keyPrefix ? (keyPrefix + "_") : ""

  const queryKeys = Object.keys(queryObject)
  const queryArray = queryKeys.map(key => {
    const value = queryObject[key]
    if (value) {
      if (isDictionary(value)) {
        return createQuery(value, keyPrefix + key + "_")
      }

      return keyPrefix + encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(String(value))
    }
    return ""
  })

  return queryArray.filter(Boolean).join("&")
}
```

#### isDictionary Helper

I used `isDictionary` helper here too, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304401/javascript-check-if-dictionary/71975382#71975382)

#### Usage

You need to put `?` in the beginning of your endpoint plus `createQuery`

```
fetch("/test?" + createQuery({ foo: 12, bar: "@user->here", object: { test: "test", bird: { super: { ultra: { mega: { deep: "human" }, shop: 7 } }, multiple: [1, 2, 3] } } }))
```

###### Result

```
foo=12&bar=%40user-%3Ehere&object_test=test&object_bird_super_ultra_mega_deep=human&object_bird_super_ultra_shop=7&object_bird_multiple=1%2C2%2C3
```

or

```
foo: 12
bar: @user->here
object_test: test
object_bird_super_ultra_mega_deep: human
object_bird_super_ultra_shop: 7
object_bird_multiple: 1,2,3
```

[image]

#### Conclusion

We got different snippets you can choose from depending on your goals.